# C++ Weird Issues with Dynamic cast - Polyrmophism (Changed bool)

Tags: vector

I am trying to dynamic_cast an instance from a vector by

```
AWorld.Unit_IndexB = AWorld.topof_CityIndex + 20;
    for (auto i = AWorld.topof_CityIndex; i < AWorld.Unit_IndexB - 1; i++)
    {

        // unit found
        //cout << "hit" << endl;
        //int b = i - AWorld.EntitiesVector.size();

        EntityUnit a;
        a = dynamic_cast<EntityUnit*>(AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]);
        a.unit_alive;
        if (a.unit_alive == false)
        {
```

The issue is that my vector - all the EntityUnits are pushed on with a value of unit_alive = false;

Yet when I dynamic cast for some reason it always returns the unit_alive as true, note that it appears all other values are correctly cast EXCEPT BOOLEANS which all turn out false.
I know you should avoid using dynamic cast but I cant think of any other way to do it in this situation, since I need to replace an element in a vector with a new one of subclass type.

I'm doing this at the end

```
            AWorld.EntitiesVector.erase(AWorld.EntitiesVector.begin() + i);
            AWorld.EntitiesVector.emplace(AWorld.EntitiesVector.begin() + i, new EntityUnit(a));



 // AWORLD
class World
{
private:
    World(const World&);
    void operator=(const World&);
public:
    const int pointsInLine = 70; // how many points in a line
    const int lines = 180; // lines must be multiple of 30
    // this is the grid size, 180 x 70, the grid is connected top to bottom and left to right, so 0x - 1x = 180x and 70y +  1y = 0  

    std::vector<void*> path;
    vector< CWaypoint*> PathToBeMade;
    vector<vector< CWaypoint*>> HiFiWaypoints;
    vector<vector< CWaypoint*>> LoFiWaypoints;
    vector<CWaypoint*>JumpPoints;
    vector<vector< CWaypoint*>> AIRCRAFTWaypoints;
    vector<vector< CWaypoint*>> NukeWaypoints;

    vector <CEntity*>EntitiesVector;
    vector <EntityCity*>CitiesVector;
    vector <EntityUnit*>UnitsVector;

    int topof_CityIndex; // beginning of city index is always 0
    int topof_UnitIndex; // beginning of unit index is top of city index + 1
    int Unit_IndexB; // Where blu's unit index begins
    int Unit_IndexG; // where greens unit index begins
    int Unit_IndexY; // Where yellow's unit index begins
    int index_current_entities;


    bool showConsidered; // used in pathfinding
    bool AllowPoles; // This bool controls whether the pathfinder will allow something to head 
                     // north or south of the poles, bear in mind, this  is for nukes & aircraft only
    bool gamestarted = false;

    int source_x, source_y;
    int target_x, target_y;

    int northpoley; // maximum point north - excluding nukes
    int southpoley; // maxmimum point south - excluding nukes

    const int max_units = 100;
    tle::IModel* P;

    string unitdefs[15];
```

Comment: That should be `EntityUnit *a;` - I imagine that's a typo in the question as the code wouldn't compile without wonky overloaded assignment operators otherwise. Please also share the declaration of `AWorld`.

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks that worked, you were correct.... something so simple I'm sorry.

Comment: It shouldn't even compile at the line  
    `EntityUnit a;`
    `a = dynamic_cast<EntityUnit*>(AWorld.EntitiesVector[i]);`

Comment: @Mochan, I can tell you it certainly did... how odd.